# FFMPEG (Java / Bramp) : [mp3 @ 000001fb5ac62700] No mimetype is known for stream 0, cannot write an attached picture

Tags: java, spring-boot, ffmpeg, bramp

Estoy tratando de convertir un archivo mp3 a otro archivo mp3 con FFMPEG.

El código que uso es este:

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");

String outputPath = env.getProperty("spring.servlet.multipart.location");

FFmpegBuilder builder;

            
builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
        .setInput(file.getAbsolutePath())
        .overrideOutputFiles(true)
        
        .addOutput(outputPath + "File_" + fileNameNoExtension + ".mp3")
            .setFormat("mp3")
        
        .disableSubtitle()
        
        .setAudioChannels(GlobalVariables.AUDIO_CHANNELS)
        .setAudioCodec(GlobalVariables.AUDIO_CODEC)
        .setAudioSampleRate(GlobalVariables.AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE)
        .setAudioBitRate(GlobalVariables.AUDIO_BIT_RATE)
        .setVideoCodec(GlobalVariables.VIDEO_CODEC)
        .setVideoFrameRate(GlobalVariables.VIDEO_FRAME_RATE, 1)
        .setVideoResolution(GlobalVariables.VIDEO_RESOLUTION)
        .setStrict(FFmpegBuilder.Strict.EXPERIMENTAL)
        .done();
        
FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);

executor.createJob(builder).run();

return new File(outputPath + "File_" + fileNameNoExtension + fileExtension);
```

El error que obtengo al hacer esto es...

> [mp3 @ 000001fb5ac62700] No mimetype is known for stream 0, cannot write an attached picture.

Curiosamente, aunque he tardado mucho rato en darme cuenta, este fallo lo obtengo solo en aquellos archivos que tienen una imagen asociada (En el explorador de archivos de Windows, veo la "carátula" en lugar del icono por defecto que tendría un mp3)

En cuanto el mimetype, juraría que está bien (al menos en lo que respecta al audio), porque haciendo esto se imprime el "1":

```
FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
String mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(file.getAbsolutePath());

if(!mimeType.equals(null)) {
    if(mimeType.contains("audio")) {
        System.out.println(1);
        fileType = "mp3";
        fileExtension = ".mp3";
        return;
    }else if(mimeType.contains("video")) {
        System.out.println(2);
        fileType = "mp4";
        fileExtension = ".mp4";
        return;
    }
}
```

Alguien sabe qué está pasando exactamente y/o cómo podría solucionar esto?

Un millón de gracias!

Comment: seguro la caratula debe tener un mime type tambien especifico...

Comment: Hola @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso. La verdad es que no tengo ni idea, pero en cualquier caso no sé cómo solucionarlo. La respuesta que yo mismo he publicado, aunque no resuelve el problema, sirve para mi caso concreto  (y puede que para alguno más), pero no la marcaré como respuesta a la espera de que alguien proponga una que no implique cargarse la carátula del archivo.

Comment: creo que deberías de publicar el problema en el github oficial del plugin/extensión: https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper/issues/105

Comment: hasta donde veo lo conveniente seria extraer la caratula; guardarla en ram y al momento de guardar en disco pasarle la caratula nuevamente con  `= new FFmpegBuilder().addInput()`

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, sobre lo de publicarlo en el GitHub del autor, me parece buena idea. Así lo haré! Y sobre esto último que dices, podrías publicarlo como respuesta: Parece una buena idea!

Comment: lo siento no desarrollo en java solo es una idea.

Answer (score 0):

No he encontrado la solución exacta a mi problema, pero sí que he logrado poder convertir los mp3 conflictivos.

Al final he optado por quitarles la carátula a los archivos antes de procesarlos. Para ello he usado el argumento "-map 0:a", que solo tiene en cuenta las pistas de audio a la hora de procesar el archivo. Es decir, que si se usa con un vídeo, aunque lo reconvirtamos a mp4 o cualquier otro formato de vídeo, habríamos perdido la imagen.

En mi caso me sirve perfectamente porque no quiero esas carátulas para nada, ya que la única razón de subir los archivos es que se puedan reproducir online, pero no descargar.

La conversión quedaría así:

```
//Aclaración: GlobalVariables es una clase Java llena de variables
//estáticas que uso como "archivo de configuración".

FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
            
            //Archivo de entrada (con la ruta incluida)
            .setInput(file.getAbsolutePath())
            .overrideOutputFiles(true)
            
            //Archivo de salida (con la ruta incluida)
            .addOutput(outputPath + "Trailer_" + fileNameNoExtension + fileExtension)
                //Formato del archivo
                .setFormat("mp3")
                
            .addExtraArgs("-map", "0:a")
            //Esta línea limita la duración del archivo de salida
            .setDuration(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                  
            .disableSubtitle()
                
            .setAudioChannels(2)
            .setAudioCodec("libmp3lame")
            .setAudioSampleRate(FFmpeg.AUDIO_SAMPLE_48000)
            .setAudioBitRate(320000)
            //Introduzo un fade-out a los últimos 3 segundos (Start=12:Duration=3)
            .setAudioFilter("afade=out:st=12:d=3")
                
            //Esta parte de vídeo es ignorada al tratarse de mp3, 
            //pero la dejo por si alguien la consulta.
            .setVideoCodec(GlobalVariables.VIDEO_CODEC)
            .setVideoFrameRate(GlobalVariables.VIDEO_FRAME_RATE, 1)
            .setVideoResolution(GlobalVariables.VIDEO_RESOLUTION)
            .setVideoFilter("fade=out:st=12:d=3")
                
            .setStrict(FFmpegBuilder.Strict.EXPERIMENTAL)
            .done();
        
    FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);
        
    executor.createJob(builder).run();
        
    return new File(outputPath + "Trailer_" + fileNameNoExtension + fileExtension);
```

Gracias a esta maravillosa comunidad!! Ojala esto acabe ayudando a alguien! :D